# Having problems understanding the logic on how to print this star shape

Tags: c, loops

I'm having problems printing out the following star shape:

```
n=10

     *
    * * 
   *   *
  *     *
 *       *
*         *
 *       *
  *     *
   *   *
    * *
     *
```

I am aware of the general steps we take when printing star shapes, but what eludes me is the bottom right "diagonal" part that needs to be printed. I can manage printing this:

```
     *
    * * 
   *   *
  *     *
 *       *
*         
 *       
  *     
   *   
    * 
     *
```

And here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int n=10;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
            int k = 2*i-j;
            if(j==n/2 -i || j==n/2 +i || i==n/2 +j || /* condition */)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

// First part of the if conditional statement prints out the upper left part, the second one prints the
// upper right part and the third one prints the lower left part of the star shape.

    return 0;
}
```

Now I tried everything I really could to figure out a formula to see the pattern and relation between `i` and `j` but I simply can't figure it out.

Thanks for taking your time to help!

EDIT: Explanation:  First part of the if conditional statement prints out the upper left part, the second one prints the upper right part and the third one prints the lower left part of the star shape.

Comment: Explain which of the three existing conditions print which set of "*" and why. That will allow you to find the missing one.

Comment: I have explained that already, it is in a comment in the code, but I'll make it visible in the post too. It did not allow me to find the missing one.

Comment: You admitteldy explained which prints what, but not why and that is the relevant part.

Comment: You've essentially built the worlds worst function plotter. The condition you are looking for is "3*n/2-i == j". This is, because thats the function you are looking for :D (rewrite it as j=m*i + b, and draw pictures, to see why this works.). But now you cropped it too much, so now the loops must go up to 10 (... i<=10;...)

Comment: Why did you write `int k = 2*i-j;`? `k` is never used.

Comment: @Yunnosch my logic was this. I divided the star shape into four parts(quadrants if you like) and did each separately. For the first one, I observed it as a square n/2 * n/2 in size and shifted the main diagonal of the n*n square by n/2.

Comment: @PlatinTato Thanks for your help, I'll see to it if it fixes the problem. The quality of the code does not add any relevance to the question (code) as it can be improved, and, frankly, is in the process of improving. :)

Comment: So do that again. Shift the line of stars in the upper left by 5, i.e. n/2.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int n=10;
    for(i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<=10; j++) {
            if(j==n/2 -i || j==n/2 +i || i==n/2 +j || 3*n/2-i==j) 
                printf("*");
            else 
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces the desired outcome. Imagine it as if it was a function, with `j=m*i + b`.

The link appears to have problems. Click [here](https://www.iquilezles.org/apps/graphtoy/) and insert the functions `x+5`, `-x+5`, `x-5`  and `-x+15`.

Comment: Thanks for your output!